# Push changes to .git directory

Tags: git, directory, repo

My `.git` dir got large because I accidentally added (then removed) a few large files.

I found this [git-delete script](https://github.com/williammizuta/git-delete) that seemed to shrink the size of the `.git` dir nicely. However, I'm not able to add/commit/push changes to this directory. I get the "not up to date, please pull" error.

Anyone know how I can apply these changes to my repo?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're doing, but if it's just your own .git then you can probably "remedy" the situation by adding a `--force` to your commit command.

Comment: The `git-delete` script shrunk my local `.git`, but I want to push these changes (deletions inside .git). Trying to avoid just scraping this repo and creating another.

Comment: You can add `--force` to a push command as well. Essentially the force means that some history is being rewritten. But it appears that you are intentionally shrinking and deleting history. `git push REPO BRANCH --force` will push things. This might look like `git push origin master --force`.

Comment: Awesome, that worked, thanks!

Comment: Great! I'll go ahead and make it an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append `--force` or `-f` to git commands to force git to accept commits that rewrite history. **Note that rewriting history is not a good idea for public projects**. But for my own git repos that aren't public facing, I rewrite history from time to time.

After you have made your commits, you can do `git push REPO BRANCH --force` to force the change. In practice, this is often `git push origin master --force`.